# MYSQL: Pattern matching

Tags: mysql, pattern-matching

I am trying to write a sql statement that can pull a unique record by comparing it's different variations

For example, I have a unique record of a movie let's say Bad Boys II.

But users do search for; 
 bad boys 2
 badboys2 >
 badboys II (2003) 
 bad boys 2 (2003)
 etc.

.... LOWER(movie_title) LIKE '%$search_query%'

The above query does not return the unique record i was hoping to get. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: This is pattern matching, not pattern recognition. The two are very different.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132382/mysql-query-like-search-and-using-strings-with-symbols

Comment: If you're using default collations, comparisons are not case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following: 
1) Put the words from the string in an array 
2) Look for a match with each word:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE LOWER(movie_title) LIKE '%$search_words[$i]%'
```

Howether, if you search for "bad booys 2" for example with this code you will get all movies which contain the words "bad", "boys" and 2.